Pointwise and uniform convergence of graph function without term
I've got the task to check the following function for pointwise and uniform convergence:
Picture of Function
But I'm already struggling because there is only a draft of the function, no term exists. I tried $f_n(x):= max(2^n - 2^{2n+1}|x - 2^{-n-1}|,0)$, this works well for $x = 0$ and for $x = 2^{-n-1}$, however not for $x=2^{-n}$. Could you help me to first of all get the term right?

The first linear function is $f(x)=x(2^n/2^{n+1}))=(1/2)x$ for $0\leq x\leq1/2^{n+1}$. The second linear function is $f(x)=-2^{2n+1}x+2^n+\dfrac{1}{2^{n+1}-2^n}$ for $1/2^{n+1}\leq x\leq1/2^n$. For $1/2^n\leq x\leq 1$ the function is a constant $0$. Thus, taking the limits as n approaches infinity, only the constant part would be left. You may check that the function converges uniformly to that constant on the interval (0,1].

Hey, isn’t it $2^n \cdot 2^{n+1} \cdot x$ in the first interval? And regarding the second interval, I didn’t get how e.g. $x = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ leads to $f_n(x) = 2^n$?
